# Use Ansible to launch Google Compute instance with Customer Managed Encryption Key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible

Is there a way to launch *using ansible* Google compute instances with customer *managed* (not customer supplied) encryption keys used for the disks?

Both of these modules seem to only support customer-supplied keys:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gcp_compute_disk_module.html
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gcp_compute_instance_module.html

Answer (score -1):

As you can read in [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/customer-managed-encryption) document, you have two options for key encryption keys in Compute Engine:

> - Use Cloud Key Management Service to create and manage key encryption keys. For more information, see Key management. This topic
>     provides details about this option, known as customer-managed
>     encryption keys (CMEK).
> - Create and manage your own key encryption keys. For information about this option, known as customer-supplied encryption keys (CSEK),
>     see Encrypting Disks with Customer-Supplied Encryption Keys.

Also you have [here](https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/) all the encryption options in Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: I'm aware of what my options are. The option I want is CMEK. The question is how I can do so with ansible.